# How to include php file based on navigation bar

Tags: php, include, href

Hey guys Id like to know what should I put in my href to include files from my class folder.

My site folder structure

```
folder-class-head.php
            -home.php
            -setting.php
            -footer.php
      -index.php
```

This is my head.php look like. What should I fill in the href in order to include the the file in my class folder?

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
   <a href="">Home</a> <a href="">Setting</a>
```

my index.php is that the right way to do if statement?

```
<?
include "class/head.php";
    <--body start-->
   if (do= home.php){
include "class/home.php";
}

if (do= setting.php){

    include "class/setting.php";
}
<--body end -->
<--footer area-->
include "class/footer.php";
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add like , &page=home to the href, and check if it is home page,

```
if($_GET['page']=='home')
{
include "class/home.php";
}
```

Comment: Now I got another problem. How to add 3 more page

Answer (score 0):

> my index.php is that the right way to do if statement?

No. Totally no.

In php, `if/elseif/else`, those are condition statements, control structure.

`do/while` represents a loop.

One very common and usual way to load appropriate piece of script with PHP is to use GET SUPERGLOBAL variable.

[PHP do/while](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.do.while.php)
[PHP if statement](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php)
[PHP $_GET](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)